# Android GCM, gradle can't sync properly

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to GCM and trying it for the first time.
I followed the documentation as google guide us to.
I tried to build and run the project with gradle files set up as followed:

```
dependencies {  
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

---

But I'm getting the next Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0."

---

When I tried to change it to 8.3.0 or 8.3+ I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sarigbrand/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Error:(18) Tag  attribute name has invalid character '>'.
>   Error:(14) Tag  attribute name has invalid character '>'."

**This issue make my debug.manifest all red and full of errors and my project won't sync at all**

---

**Other things I tried:**

1. google-services versions - 2.0.0-alpha9, 1.5.0-beta2, 1.5.0, 1.3.0.
2. I tried to delete android studio and reinstall (old version - 1.3, new version 1.5)
3. I tried to download gradle 2.10 or run it from the wrapper file (I was asked to to that before I reinstalled):

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
   ```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" /> <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.sarigbrand.pushnotification.google_measurement_service"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

---

[image: print screen]

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from project-level `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Use this to reference GCM service in your `app build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

This is working for me

Comment: Ok just tried that, I was asked to update to gradle 2.2 which I just did but I get this Error now: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
<a href="openFile:/Users/sarigbrand/AndroidStudioProjects/PushNotification/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: when I click on open file he is referencing me to the app gradle file in row > apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: You should remove that `apply plugin` row and then resync gradle

Comment: of course I tried that as well, I get the same error when trying 8.3.0, it opens up the manifesto file i get a lot of errors with syntax errors (which shouldn't happen imo)

Comment: Error:(14) Tag <permission> attribute name has invalid character '>'.
Error:(18) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character '>'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/sarigbrand/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @Roee would you mind posting it? Looks like there's a syntax error or invalid char

Comment: I added it, as you can see its the debug.manifest file and not the regular manifest no idea what to do with it